# Running PHP file on XAMPP, nothing happens

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Today I installed xampp v3.2.1 and my Apache and MySQL servers are running as you can see:

[image: XAMPP screenshot]

I am worried about that red thing I marked down with rectangle.
However I can access to `localhost:8080`, but when I try to run PHP file (e.g. `localhost/hey.php`) it just shows blank space.

Comment: You're running Apache on port 8080, not port 80, so that red text isn't useful to you.  You're going to have to look at your error log.  We cannot magically know what's in your log files.  You have to tell us.

Comment: Is there any other service running on the port 8080?

Comment: To run a php script, say `index.php` then you need tp add the port to the url in the web browser. i.e `http://localhost:8080/index.php`. If you use the `admin` button in the 'control panel' -> 'phpInfo()'. it will show you a lot of useful information?

Comment: Well this is working http://localhost:8080/index.php but i still get that red apache with port 80. Thanks for help

Comment: @Yelyah because you have another application running that is using port 80, you need to find which application and remove or change its configuration, if u want your wamp to use that port. Skype, another webserver, use `netstat -ano` on the prompt command to check that and match the PID against your task manager

Answer (score 0):

Your port is conflicting. May be IIS server installed on your computer occupied this port.So, try to disable it.
You can check port using below command in linux.

```
# netstat -tulpn
```